# Haskell: Show recursive data type

Tags: haskell

I have a custom recursive data type

```
data Vertex = Vertex Int [Vertex]
```

where `Int` is an index number of the vertex and `[Vertex]` are vertices adjacent to this vertex.

Now, I want to show this data type as a list of indexes of vertices: Let's say there are two vertices `a` and `b` with indexes `1` and `2` respectively and they are adjacent to each other. My output should look like this: `"[(1, [2])]"`.

I figured out that I must write an instance of `Show` for `Vertex`. And here is my problem, how can I show recursive data type? I think Haskell's laziness might be the solution?

**EDIT - Example**

As I mentioned above I have `Vertex` data type. Now, I have an adjacency list with vertices and their adjacent vertices:

```
adjacencyList :: [Vertex]
adjacencyList = [a, b, c]
 where a = Vertex 6 [b]
       b = Vertex 7 [a, c]
       c = Vertex 12 [b]
```

When I write this

```
print adjacencyList
```

I would like to have output that looks like this:

```
[(6, [7]), (7, [6, 12]), (12, [7])]
```

Comment: I would refrain from using `show` to do that - you get the benefit of `Show` when you have output that you want to feed your functions again as a Haskell data structure, better make something like a `ppShow`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need direct adjacency, then recursiveness is not really an issue, since you can just do

```
toAdjacency :: [Vertex] -> [(Int, [Int])]
toAdjacency = map outFrom
  where
    outFrom (Vertex i vs) = (i, map inTo vs)
    inTo (Vertex i _) = i
```

Then `show . toAdjacency` is exactly the format you are after.